# Access denied to root folder and files but allow subfolders and files via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I deny listing the contents of a parent/root files, but allow access to all sub-folders and their files ?
Example

```
**-Root Folder (Do not access)**
    -index.php (cannot be accessed)
    -demo.php (cannot be accessed)
    -.htaccess (for achieving this)
    **-Subfolder-1 (Grant access all files and folders)**
        -index.php
        -example.php
        -Subfolder-1 -Subfolder
    **-Subfolder-2 (Grant access all files and folders)**
        -index.php
        -example.php
        -Subfolder-2 -Subfolder
```

Comment: "deny listing the contents of" - deny access to the files themselves or "list the contents of" the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default behaviour is to allow access, so you could just block access to the files in the root using mod_rewrite.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Block access (403 Forbidden) to the root folder itself
RewriteRule ^$ - [F]

# 403 Forbidden for any file request in the document root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.\w{2,5}$ - [F]
```

The second rule above matches requests for files (that include a file extension) in the root directory only. If this request also maps to an actual file then a "403 Forbidden" response is returned. If the request does not map to a real file then a standard "404 Not Found" response is returned (by default).

If, however, you just want to send a 404 (or 403) for all requests to (what "looks like") files in the root then use the following instead, removing the preceding *condition*:

```
# 404 Not Found for any request that looks like a file request in the document root
# - including the root directory itself
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.\w{2,5})?$ - [R=404]
```

By making the entire pattern optional (ie. by surrounding in `^(.....)?$`) it matches the root directory as well.

Comment: I appreciate your effort and time. I have pasted the above code  but it  does not do anything on my localhost. (XAMPP)

Comment: Oops I am sorry @MrWhite , Actually yes other pages is disabled and working fine to redirect 404 or 403 but index.php is accessible i.e. http://localhost/test/ or  http://localhost/test and  http://localhost/test/index.php is accessible . I want all types are not accessible.

Comment: @AmritJha Sorry, the regex should read `{2,5}` (2 comma 5), not `{2.5}` (2 dot 5). If you'd used a dot then it shouldn't have done anything (since it would not have matched a valid file).  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AmritJha I've updated my answer to block the root directory itself. I take it from your comment, that the `.htaccess` file is located inside the `/test` subdirectory?

Comment: Awesome , It's working and I am accepting your answer. Thank you so much brother :)